# How to do Real time communication between Django server and my device, using django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, raspberry-pi, iot, psql

I am creating an IoT project with a simple switch on and off event that is sent by the user to Django serve. And my device also connected to the Internet.

Here I want to get data to the device when the user does any action for the device using the Django Rest framework.

Getting data real-time using Django rest framework.

Here the device is raspberry PI.

Is this possible? If yes Please give me any reference.

Comment: Connecting to Django server is realtime, in the sense that your Django user uses some sort of client to make a connection and issues a POST request to the Django server.  Your Django server will not be making a connection to your raspberry device, unless there is something running on you raspberry that will accept connections.  So your raspberry device will have to be polling your Django server for new on off events.

Answer (score 2):

You can host websockets by yourself with [django-channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/),or you can use third-party message middleware like [pubnub](https://www.pubnub.com/) which has python sdk for raspberry PI and java/objects-c sdk for your android/iOS devices.

By the way,i think django and drf is too large for raspberry PI.If your goal is simply to turn light on and off,pubnub is your best choice.

I have done similar project like you,I choose pubnub as message channel.Use android device send command within pubnub to raspberry PI,and raspberry PI control it's GPIO to turn on or off relay.Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks, for help. And this is only the prototype model. After that, I will make full home automation. Is it okay to go with Django and rest framework?

Comment: If the system will get larger,you should use django and drf for that.And use pc to replace raspberry PI as server.And your single device need have wifi or eth module to keep long-connect(web-socket) to your server

Answer (score 0):

You can use django-websocket-redis package for this purpose

you can directly push messages to UI using this package

Please have a look at this [Package](https://github.com/jrief/django-websocket-redis)